# Expanding expression using Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have come across the following equivalency:

```
p(A, B|C) = p(A, B, C) / P(C)
```

I am trying to understand why/how the left side expands to the right side.

My attempts:

```
p(A, Z) = p(A|Z)/P(Z) = P( A | (B|C) ) / P( (B|C) )
```

But I have no idea what to make of that or if its even remotely on the right track...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making a variable to represent $B \mid C$, try to make a variable represent the event $A \wedge B$ (i.e., "$A$ and $B$")

Let $Z := A \wedge B$.

$$p(A,B \mid C) = p(Z \mid C) = \frac{p(Z,C)}{p(C)} = \frac{p(A,B,C)}{p(C)}$$

Comment: In other words, my understanding of the precedence of "|" is wrong? Is the expression meant to read p( (A, B) | C) and not p(A, (B|C)), or is it just that both are equivalent? Or something else?

Comment: @Colton Yes, that's about it. It's the probability, if you know $C$, of $A$ and $B$ occurring.

Comment: So if the expression was explicitly p(A, (B|C)) it would be a different story, and P( (A, B) | C) is implicit. Alrighty, thanks to both of you!

Comment: @Colton Just FYI, $p(A, (B\mid C))$ is never used. You operate either in a world where you know $C$ occurs, or a world where you don't know anything about $C$. You can't really separate things like that, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. It's just a matter of correctly placing parentheses.

Consider the question as:

$$ P((A\cap B) | C) $$  and then the usual law of conditional probability applies where

$$ P((A\cap B) | C) = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C )}{ P(C)}$$